Auto-include: Cycle detected
Can someone explain why EF is failing here?

System.InvalidOperationException: Cycle detected while auto-including navigations: 'CatalogPage.Pages'. To fix this issue, either don't configure at least one navigation in the cycle as auto included in OnModelCreating or call 'IgnoreAutoInclude' method on the query.

Model:
public class CatalogPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public string? Layout { get; init; }
    public int? RoleId { get; init; }
    public int CatalogPageId { get; init; }
    public int OrderId { get; init; }
    public int IconId { get; init; }
    public bool Enabled { get; init; }
    public bool Visible { get; init; }
    public ICollection<CatalogPage> Pages { get; init; } = [];
}

I am auto loading Pages...
When I try and fetch like so, it fails:
var parentlessPages = await dbContext.Set<CatalogPage>()
    .Where(x => x.CatalogPageId == -1)
    .ToListAsync();


Can't tell without seeing the other classes and exactly which properties are auto-including.

I think its getting a little tripped up on the recursion somehow.

The properties are all in my question, all primitive types. I don't see how EF can go wrong here?

So, apparently you have Pages configured as AutoInclude (in the first version you had another navigation, so we had to be sure). A self-reference is always a cycle. It can't possibly auto-include. There's not a single SQL statement that can do that.

So you're telling me EF is incapable of having related entities recursively?

No, it never could in one statement, with or without AutoInclude, since every LINQ query is translated into one SQL statement. Recursively querying a hierarchy always requires manual coding and multiple SQL queries. (Unless you query the entire table with tracking).
